# Show input values in a p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input element, what I want to achieve is whenever I type into the input, the characters will be inserted into a p tag and will be displayed. The code I have below partially works. The problem I have with my code is the characters will start to show in the p tag when I type the second character. I want it to start showing after 1st typed character. How can I achieve this?

```js
$('input').keypress(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 0) {
    $('p').html($(this).val())
  }
});

$('input').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == null) {
      $('p').html('')
    }
    $('p').html($(this).val())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<p></p>
```

Comment: Why do you use `keypress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `input` event is ideal for this case. Also catches copy-paste into the field.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  $('p').html($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<p></p>
```

Comment: any idea why keypress didn't work?

Comment: @seriously the value would not be updated yet.

Comment: I would also add that using `$('input').on(`  and `$('p')` for such a specific task is a no-no. Use rather a more specific selector than just *any Input* and *all Paragraphs*.

Answer (score -1):

You just use keyup function.

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 0) {
    $('p').html($(this).val())
  }
});

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8) {
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == null) {
      $('p').html('')
    }
    $('p').html($(this).val())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<p></p>
```

Comment: didn't downvote but the input event is a better way.

Comment: Just no. Always, when in need to use a `value` use the `"input"` event. Such will handle any kind of *value change*, such as i.e: a copy/paste. Can be easily forgotten as a novice, but you don't always need a *keyboard* to change a, Input Element value.